# Adding link to the database-called element in while loop

Tags: php

I want to add link to the searched element which is done through ajax. In search.php I've following code but apparently it's not working.

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res_old))
{
  echo "<li style='border-bottom: 1px solid #A5ACB2; padding:5px; margin-left:-40px;margin-right:5px;>";
  $productid=$row['productid'];
  echo "<a href='search.php?productid='$productid'>";
  echo $row['brand'];
  echo "&nbsp";
  echo $row['product_name'];
  echo "&nbsp";
  echo $row['short_desc'];
  echo "&nbsp";
  echo "&#8377;";
  echo $row['price'];
  echo "</a>";
  echo "<br>";
  echo "</li>";
}
```

Anybody can shade some light on why it's not working?
Just link is not being added, results are coming fine.

Comment: Can you define *Not Working* in brief ?

Comment: Results are coming fine but those are without <a> links actually, so I can not click them & go to the desired page. They are coming as non-clickable entities.

Comment: Post your result html too.

Comment: It's done through ajax, everything is coming fine but without clickable entities, coming just as a text. Do you want me to put the whole code in here?

Comment: I mean are you getting proper HTML in response ? Or you can put response you getting in your ajax, only part related to issue. Also post your ajax call code.

Comment: Yes I'm getting proper HTML in response, everything is coming absolutely fine, just as a text. The problem simply is <a> is not being attached to any of the elements mentioned above. It's working like there is no <a> in code.

Comment: @ShanilSoni See my answer for why that is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The actual problem here is not a missing tag, but unmatched quotes.. or rather, misplaced quotes.

Here is your current opening tag:

```html
<a href='search.php?productid='$productid'>
```

If you will notice the syntax highlighting, it becomes clear what is wrong here; since attribute values can be denoted by quotes, you actually end your attribute value at the first quote it sees, thus giving a malformed a tag.

If you want your code to work, you have to either escape those quotes, or do something else:

```
<a href='search.php?productid=$productid'>
```

For instance, the above has removed the quotes, so the tag parses correctly now.

Of course, this isn't the only error:

```
echo "<li style='border-bottom: 1px solid #A5ACB2; padding:5px; margin-left:-40px;margin-right:5px;>";
//                                                                            Right here           ^, this should be an ending single quote.
```

On this line, you never close your style attribute with a quote, thus messing up any following html.

The corrected line is as follows:

```
echo "<li style='border-bottom: 1px solid #A5ACB2; padding:5px; margin-left:-40px;margin-right:5px;'>";
```

Comment: Yeah I got the error, but removing that didn't have any impact.:(

Comment: @ShanilSoni I missed one, please see the correction.

Comment: That worked like a charm, & I wasted almost 30 minutes on single quote. God!!:)

Answer (score 0):

Well, I am not sure whether this is the reason but aren't you missing a quote after 'productid' interpolation to balance the quote before 'search.php'?

Your Code:

```
echo "<a href='search.php?productid='$productid'>";
```

Possible Solution:

```
echo "<a href=\"search.php?productid='$productid'\">";
```

PS: I don't have much php knowledge :)

Comment: Nope, that can not be a solution.

Comment: Well, I just tried this code on an online php compiler and it is providing a working solution(i.e., a working link tag). Maybe some other error as well. Anyways, seems that you figured it out. :)